# Create empty object or object with null values for already known keys

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object

I am playing around with JavaScript and AngularJS since a few days and I am not sure about the following:

I am working on a sample project in which a user is able to create a new car with just a few properties stored in an JS object like this:

```
var car = {
    color: 'black',
    seating: 'leather',
    fuelconsumption: 'moderate'
}
```

The user can create a new car by clicking on an add-button. Angular then creates a new instance of a car and the user can specify the wishes for new car.

However, should I create an empty object like

```
var car = {}
```

and add the needed keys using the bound text inputs or should I do something different?

Since the properties of a new car are known a-priori I could also create an object with the needed keys and `null` as their values like this:

```
var car = {
    color: null,
    seating: null,
    fuelconsumption: null
}
```

Which way would be more preferable due to e.g. best-practise?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Javascript, there is often not a need to initialize a property to `null`.  This is because referencing a property that has not been initialized just harmlessly returns `undefined` which can work just as well as `null`.  This is obviously different than some other languages (Java, C++) where properties of an object must be declared before you can reference them in any way.

What I would think might make sense in your case is to create a constructor function for creating a `car` object because you will presumably be creating more than one car and all possible car objects won't be known at the time you write the code.  So, you create a constructor function like this:

```
function Car(color, seating, fuel) {
    this.color = color;
    this.seating = seating;
    this.fuelConsumption = fuel;
}
```

Then, you can create a new Car object like this:

```
var c = new Car('black', 'leather', 'moderate');
console.log(c.color);   // 'black'
```

Answer (score 9):

You can do it both ways. I prefer creating the empty object using `{}` and then adding the needed props but you can make it by defining the props with the initialization of the value:

```
 var car = {};
```

or

```
var car = { 
    color: null,
    seating: null,
    fuelconsumption: null
};
```

Just like you did. I dont think there is a best practise for doing this.
But maybe the values shoud point the needed type of the data saved this property.

Example:

```
var car = { 
    color:"",
    seating: "",
    fuelconsumption: ""
};
```

**In you case "" is fine.**

If using number `NaN, undefined`.

If using strings `""`.

If using objects or arrays `{} []`.

If using some kind of boolen values `true/false`